# Prolog Trying to Print But Get Errror

Tags: prolog

Why do I get the error "uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,'Jack'/0),(is)/2)" when printing the name.

"test(180)."

```
info('Mike','Ross',166).
info('Jack','John',180).

test(Name):- info(Y,_,T),T>170, Name is Y.
```

Comment: `is` is not an assigment operator. You can use `Name = Y` here, but you need to understand it is not really assignment but unification. https://www.metalevel.at/equality

Answer (score 1):

That's because `is` is the instruction to perform arithmetic evaluation of the right-hand-side.

In this case, `Y`, which is instantiated to `Jack`.

However, `Jack/0` (`Jack` with no arguments) is *not* an arithmetic function. Hence, an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `is` at all, your rule should be:

```
test(Name):- info(Name,_,T),T>170.
```

then:

```
?- test(Name).
Name = 'Jack'.
```